# Set F# list as null for serialisation

Tags: f#, json.net

I'm using F# alongside a JSON data-store making use of the JSON.NET library. I'm trying to utilise F# structures and types where possible and have run into the following issue. Say I wish to store the following data structure,

```
type A = {
    id : int
    name : string
    posts : string list
}
```

Creation works fine, but to update just the stored `name` field I need to send a JSON record that omits the `posts` field. Using the empty list won't work as the persistence system will assume that I wish to replace the existing posts with an empty list and thus overwrite them. From the [JSON.NET docs](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/html/ReducingSerializedJSONSize.htm) I've read a field can be omitted from serialisation by setting it to `null`,

```
let updatedEntry = { id : 0, name : "Fred", posts = null }
```

However the F# compiler will give an error stating that the type `list` can not be set to `null`. Is there anyway to accomplish this from within F#, perhaps an attribute I'm unaware of? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two ways you could do this easily:

#### Option 1

Use the System.Collections.Generic.List type, which can be null:

```
> type A = {id: int; name:string; posts: System.Collections.Generic.List<string> };;

type A =
  {id: int;
   name: string;
   posts: System.Collections.Generic.List<string>;}

> let a = {id=5; name="hello"; posts=null};;

val a : A = {id = 5;
             name = "hello";
             posts = null;}
```

#### Option 2

The other, more idiomatic way, would be to use the Option type:

```
> type A = {id: int; name:string; posts: string list option };;

type A =
  {id: int;
   name: string;
   posts: string list option;}

> let a = {id=5; name="there"; posts=None};;

val a : A = {id = 5;
             name = "there";
             posts = null;}
```

Note that you'd compare the `posts` member to `None` rather than `null`.

Handy reading: [Option types](http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/the-option-type/)

---

**Edit**

(After some searching & experimentation) you could use boxing to still use F# types as the values:

```
> type A = {id: int; name:string; posts: System.Object };;

type A =
  {id: int;
   name: string;
   posts: Object;}

> let a = {id=5; name="foo"; posts=null};;

val a : A = {id = 5;
             name = "foo";
             posts = null;}

> let b = {id=6; name="bar"; posts=(box [])};;

val b : A = {id = 6;
             name = "bar";
             posts = [];}
```

But I'd stick with the Option type, personally

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yep, they were the two approaches I was considering. A general .NET list type works although I was keen to stay within the F# ecosystem. Using an Option type is certainly more idiomatic and probably the way I'll go - I just wanted to see if I could 'get away' with a `null` as it's only required within the persistence layer. Cheers.

Comment: It seemed to me like there might be an attribute that allowed nulls when I read your question, but I only wanted to give "proper" options as an answer :) There is the `AllowNullLiteral` attribute, but I tried that on a record field and it gave me a " This attribute is not valid for use on this language element" error. Maybe there's a different attribute that would work? After looking around a bit more it doesn't look like it's possible.

Comment: How interesting - I need to read more about 'boxing'. But yes, as you suggest, I'll stick with an Option type as it will make the meaning of the code more explicit, and is the 'proper' way :). Thank you.

Comment: @mands I'd forgotten about boxing until I saw it while searching for more on this, then I recalled having read about it at some point. (It must have made a _big_ impression!) Glad I could be of help :)

Comment: @mands note that you can avoid some typing if you use the `ResizeArray` type alias instead of `System.Collections.Generic.List`.